# Change the starting value of a serial - Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I've a little problem with serial : From a file, I filled my database in which I have a client ID (it is a serial and it is my primary key). I have 300 clients so 300 client ID (1 to 300). Now my problem is, I've a form for new clients.I cannot add them because when I add a client, my program adds the client with ID 1 or the ID 1 is already assigned to another client.

So my question is : is it possible to change the starting value of a serial for to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 60):

You can alter a sequence using `RESTART WITH` to change the current sequence number;

```
ALTER SEQUENCE test_seq RESTART WITH 300;
```

To get the sequence name if you created it using the serial keyword, use

```
SELECT adsrc FROM pg_attrdef WHERE adrelid = (SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'table name goes here');
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1d081/1).

Comment: So for to change the starting value, I need to create a sequence.

Comment: @user1086267: a `serial` column **is** populated by a sequence. Please do read the manual. This is all documented there.

Comment: @user1086267 To get the sequence name if you created it using the `serial` keyword, use `SELECT adsrc 
FROM pg_attrdef 
WHERE adrelid = (SELECT oid FROM
    pg_class WHERE relname = 'table name goes here');`

Comment: `adsrc` column is no longer present in latest posgres

Answer (score 20):

**PostgreSQL**

```
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_columnname_seq RESTART WITH anynumber;
```

Example:

```sql
ALTER SEQUENCE test_table_rec_id_seq RESTART WITH 4615793;
```

Answer (score 5):

if your Postgresql version is higher than the upper answer, you could try getting serial key with `select pg_get_serial_sequence('ingredients', 'id');`

and
`SELECT adsrc FROM pg_attrdef WHERE adrelid = (SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'ingredients');`

Answer (score 3):

For those who try to point to specific schema's table, here's the query you will need to execute.

```
// To get the sequence name
SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('"yourSchema"."yourTable"', 'yourColumn');
//Output: yourSchema."yourTable_yourColumn_seq"

ALTER SEQUENCE yourSchema."yourTable_yourColumn_seq" RESTART WITH 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above did not work for what I needed.

I needed a serial id to use as a primary key that started from 1000, rather than 1.

In order to do this, I created a standard serial column:

```
ALTER table my_table ADD COLUMN new_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

and then updated that column:

```
UPDATE my_table set new_id = new_id + 1000;
```

I then joined that table to the table with existing non-consecutive id numbers under 1000.

Comment: yeah @aclong I'm not sure why the downvote either. I can say a year later than i never ran into any problems with this method. Perhaps it would be better to use the combination of two columns as the p key. It could be `PRIMARY KEY (source, serial_column)` where source was ['source_1', 'source_2'] and serial_column was the union of two serial columns starting from 1 so that `'source_1, 1` would be  unique from `source_2, 1` but that would not have worked as well for my purposes. You can upvote if you like :)