# Does postgres support to set start value at serial definition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362930/change-the-starting-value-of-a-serial-postgresql) is a question about changing serial value with `alter` key word. Can this be done in create table defintion? Like that:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname SERIAL stars 1000
);
```

Comment: Is the 1000 the starting value?

Answer (score 6):

You can try this query.Its worked for me.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1 ---> here you can mention startup nummber as you need
  CACHE 1;

CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
);
```

Answer (score 4):

## Identity Columns

There is no currently no way to do this in a `CREATE TABLE` command in PostgreSQL 9.x using the PostgreSQL-specific [serial-type syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL). However, it's coming in PostgreSQL 10 using the [standardized *Identity Columns* syntax, see my answer on it here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/169347/2639)

Here is how it will look

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id int GENERATED { ALWAYS | BY DEFAULT }
      AS IDENTITY [ ( sequence_options ) ]
);
```

Where `(sequence_options)` is `START WITH 1000`, so something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  foo_id   int   GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1000)
);
```